# How to encode special characters in GET request using NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios

How would I go about encoding a url string for a GET request?  I am specifically running into a problem where the value of a field I want to send includes an ampersand (&), which is being interpreted as a separator between fields.

I am currently creating my request as follows (the code that actually makes the call is taken from Apple's MVC Networking example, so it is probably not relevant to this issue but included for completeness)

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://.../?name=%@&nameupdated=%@", name, nameUpdated];
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
NSString *webStringUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url;

url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringUrl];
assert(url != nil);

// Call down to the network manager so that it can set up its stuff 

if (url != nil) {
    request = [[NetworkManager sharedManager] requestToGetURL:url];
    assert(request != nil);
}

RetryingHTTPOperation *updateOperation  = [[[RetryingHTTPOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
assert(updateOperation != nil);

[updateOperation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal];

[[NetworkManager sharedManager] addNetworkManagementOperation:updateOperation finishedTarget:self action:@selector(updateItemOperationDone:)];

[urlString release];
```

If the name field is something like "Bed & Breakfast" then the url string ends up as:
http://.../?name=Bed%20&%20Breakfast&....

and I end up with only "Bed " as my name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use code like the following to encode every single argument:

```
NSString *urlEncoded = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL, 
    (CFStringRef)sourceString, 
    NULL, 
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", 
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Then construct the full URL string from the separate URL-encoded fragments.

Comment: Hi ..For me I had to encode + while sending request. I have sent request by removing all characters except + like this.. NSString *urlEncoded = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL, 
    (CFStringRef)sourceString, 
    NULL, 
    (CFStringRef)@"+", 
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);. Helpful for someone and thanks for Ole Begemann. And important thing is this is for ARC enabled project.

Answer (score 7):

This is just an addition to the previous code for using ARC. This bridges correctly:

```
NSString *urlEncoded = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL, 
    (__bridge CFStringRef)sourceString, 
    NULL, 
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", 
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 url=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)url, NULL,
                                                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

for ARC